# Using Roboguice 2 without inheriting from RoboActivity

Tags: guice, roboguice

I am using a BaseActivity which handles the menu and every activity that has a menu extends from the BaseActivity.

Now I want to use roboguice but I do already have a inheritance going on there.

**How can I use guice without inheriting from RoboActivity?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just create own super class and copy into it sth like this:
https://github.com/rtyley/roboguice-sherlock/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/rtyley/android/sherlock/roboguice/activity/RoboSherlockActivity.java

Change only `SherlockActivity` to `BaseActivity`.

Comment: Worked as expected :D A little messy but it gets the job done!